# Compare two strings in powershell, regex * match, output DataSpace_ID field from string1 based on match, into switches listing string in own column

Tags: regex, powershell, multiple-matches, partial-matches

I have a list of switches in CSV and a list of data spaces where these switches are.  In my list of Data Spaces, I have a DataSpace_ID field which represents its associated DataSpace_Name.

My list of switches has a Host_Name and IP_Address fields.  What I want is using PowerShell and regex matching using Wildcards, I want to match the DataSpace field example, "ABC-COM" to the switch listing Host_Name which would be ABC-COM-3750-SW1.  I only want to match up to ABC-COM...

Then for my result I want the output, based on the matches found, to associate the DataSpace_ID value found and include it in the output of the switch listing.

Let's say I match ABC-COM = DATASPACE_ID 1 and DEF-COM = DataSpace_ID 2, and my switch data is:

```
Host_Name        IP_Address
ABC-COM-3750-SW1 IP 192.168.1.2
ABC-COM-3750-SW2 IP: 192.168.1.3 
DEF-COM-3750-SW1 IP: 192.168.3.5
DEF-COM-3750-SW2 IP: 192.168.3.6
```

So, in the end you would have this output from the switch listing based on comparison of the dataspace listing, except it would add the DataSpace_ID Column from the other comparison listing of data space names...  Switch listing Output would look like this:

```
DataSpace_ID     Host_Name        IP_Address
1                ABC-COM-3750-SW1 IP 192.168.1.2
1                ABC-COM-3750-SW2 IP: 192.168.1.3 
2                DEF-COM-3750-SW1 IP: 192.168.3.5
2                DEF-COM-3750-SW2 IP: 192.168.3.6
```

Here is my latest code revised based on some of your input, I am not getting errors any longer, however my output is not returning any results either.

```
    clear-host
    $hash.clear()
    $dataSpacesExport = Import-Csv -Path .\DataSpaces_Export.csv -Header 'DataSpace_ID', 'DataSpace_Name' -Delimiter ","
    $accessSwitchesForExport = Import-Csv -Path .\AccessSwitchesForExport.csv -Header 'Host_Name', 'IP_Address' -Delimiter ","

    # create hashtable
    $hash = @{}
    # Create Regex criteria
    $re = [regex]".+(?=-\d+)"

    $dataSpacesExport | ConvertFrom-Csv | % { $hash.Add($_,”$_”) }

    # output
    $accessSwitchesForExport | ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Select-Object @{ n = "DataSpace_ID"; e = { $hash[$re.Match($_.Host_Name).Value] } },* |
    Where-Object { $_.DataSpace_ID -ne $null }
```

My CSV files as some have asked for, example data would be:
DataSpaces and switches output examples are below in the post.  DataSpaces contain a DataSpace_ID and DataSpace_Name, and switches csv contain a Host_Name and IP_Address fields.

Output, like below, based on comparison of two csv's should show:
Matching DataSpace_ID with matching Host_Name, and its associated IP Address in final table.

Comment: Can you summarize this in 3 simple sentences ?\

Comment: Why are you trying to split your data at newlines after the import? `Import-Csv` should already have done that for you (and transformed each row into a custom object). And why do you specify the parameter `-Header`? Your input files seem to have a header row. `Imort-Csv` will automatically determine column names from the first row in the file unless you tell it otherwise. Also, comma is the default delimiter, so `-Delimiter ','` is not needed.

Comment: Hi Ansgar Wiechers, This code was me playing with different options to see what works.  So, I agree with your statements here, the extra code is not needed.

Comment: Example...Compare Network Switch names in one CSV(ABC-COM-3750-AS1) to a Network Closet name similar in naming convention (ABC-COM) from a separate CSV.  Network closet name has an ID field associated with each closet.  I need to compare switch name with network closet, and then grab the associated ID for that network closet and insert it into my switch listing as a new field called ID...  Do this for each match, using Regex method to match. [a-z0-9] etc.  Hope this helps.

Comment: To wrap up on what I mentioned, the reason I need this is because there may be network switches in my list NOT associated to a Network Closet in my database.  That Network closet CSV is an export from my database.  Any switches that don't have an associated network closet, I don't want the data, only matches.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and remove the useless code as it's only distracting from the problem you're asking about. Also, please show a sample of the second input file.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, Once approved, you will see my changes.  I removed the invalid unrelated code.  It should be cleaner to read now.

Comment: I didn't ask you to remove all of your code, just the parts of it that serve no purpose. And you still haven't shown a sample of your second input file.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, New code posted at top, also for example csv code see the examples posted at top as well.  It shows the two csv's and then what the output of hash table should look like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using a hash table.

```
$dataSpacesExport = @"
DataSpace_ID,DataSpace_Name
1,ABC-COM
2,DEF-COM
"@ 

$accessSwitchesForExport = @"
Host_Name,IP_Address
ABC-COM-3750-SW1,IP: 192.168.1.2
ABC-COM-3750-SW2,IP: 192.168.1.3 
DEF-COM-3750-SW1,IP: 192.168.3.5
DEF-COM-3750-SW2,IP: 192.168.3.6
GHI-COM-3750-SW2,IP: 192.168.3.6
"@

$re = [regex]".+(?=-\d+)"

# create hashtable
$id = @{}
$dataSpacesExport | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object { $id[$_.DataSpace_Name] = $_.DataSpace_ID }

# output
$accessSwitchesForExport | ConvertFrom-Csv |
Select-Object @{ n = "DataSpace_ID"; e = { $id[$re.Match($_.Host_Name).Value] } },* |
Where-Object { $_.DataSpace_ID -ne $null }
```

The output is as follows.

```
DataSpace_ID Host_Name        IP_Address      
------------ ---------        ----------      
1            ABC-COM-3750-SW1 IP: 192.168.1.2  
1            ABC-COM-3750-SW2 IP: 192.168.1.3 
2            DEF-COM-3750-SW1 IP: 192.168.3.5 
2            DEF-COM-3750-SW2 IP: 192.168.3.6
```

The following code is another solution. In this case, you do not need a regular expression.

```
$dataSpaces = $dataSpacesExport | ConvertFrom-Csv

$accessSwitchesForExport | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($ds in $dataSpaces) {
        if (!$_.Host_Name.StartsWith($ds.DataSpace_Name)) { continue }
        [pscustomobject]@{
            DataSpace_ID = $ds.DataSpace_ID
            Host_Name = $_.Host_Name
            IP_Address = $_.IP_Address
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the property names (`$_.HostNames`, `$ds.DataSpace_Name`, etc.) correspond to your csv headers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help!  I used bits and pieces of the recommendations above to come up with the following result which works perfectly and generates that data needed.

```
#Set Present Working Directory for path to save data to. 

#Clear any Hash Table Data prior to start of script //
$id.clear()

#Import current listing of Data Spaces and Access switches from CSV format //
$dataSpacesExport = import-csv -Header DataSpace_ID, DataSpace_Name -Path ".\DataSpaces_Export.csv"
$accessSwitchesForExport = import-csv -Header Host_Name, Device_IP -Delimiter "," -Path ".\AccessSwitchesForExport.csv"

#Regex text matching criteria //
$re = [regex]".+(?=-\d+)"

# create hashtable to store output //
$id=@{}

# Inject DataSpaces listing into Script for processing via hash table $id //
$dataSpacesExport | % {$id[$_.DataSpace_Name] = $_.DataSpace_ID}


# output - Compare Access Switch listing to DataSpaces Hashtable information, produce output to out-file sw_names.txt //
$accessSwitchesForExport |
Select-Object @{ n = "DataSpace_ID"; e = { $id[$re.Match($_.Host_Name).Value] } },* |
Where-Object { $_.DataSpace_ID -ne $null } | Out-File ./sw_names.txt -Force
```

Output is as expected and is now working.